# WSO2 API Manager Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

Tags: cookies, header, wso2-api-manager

i'm using wso2 api manager(version 2.1.0) to expose some rest api. i need to send "Cookie" as header to some of my rest api(s). I use "API Manager store" to test rest api (https://localhost:9443/store) . but when i set Cookie as Header Request i see this log in browser and call failed  :

> Refused to set unsafe header "Cookie"

but when i use any other headers like "customHeader" it works fine.

in API_HOME/repository/conf/api-manager.xml , i change this line :

```
<Access-Control-Allow-Headers>Cookie,customHeader,authorization,Access-Control-Allow-Origin,Content-Type,SOAPA</Access-Control-Allow-Headers>
```

I also enable "Enable API based CORS Configuration" in api manager publisher (https://localhost:9443/publisher)

I really stuck in this.
is there any way to set Cookie header in api manager?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actually you can't set Cookie header that way.

Browsers restrict the way you create cookies allowing you to set a cookie only for a specific domain and path and with a specific expiration time.

Cookie header is a set of all headers defined to the request domain and path, so you cannot directly overwrite this header.

Setting an HTTP Cookie involves sending Set-Cookie header with the values you want to set.

Check this out:

- [5.4.  The Cookie Header](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-5.4)
- [4.1.  Set-Cookie](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6265#section-4.1)
- [HTTP cookies explained](https://www.nczonline.net/blog/2009/05/05/http-cookies-explained/)

Comment: Many Thanks. I finally solved the problem by using Message Mediation.in publisher I enabled  Message Mediation and then set an "In Flow" message.In this mediation I set my custom header.

Comment: please can you share your mediation policy in order to know how to set a cookie?